# how add onclicklistener to a fragment from which i want to jump to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    qr= v.findViewById(R.id.qrb); 

    qr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),payphno.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    qr= v.findViewById(R.id.qrb); 

    qr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),payphno.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

was expecting to jump to another page or activity

Comment: can you tell us clearly what you want?

Comment: i want to add onclicklistener so that i could jump to another activity

Comment: As I am watching. Your code should not contain errors. He seems to be right.